# Google CDN cache failing

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

Currently deploying CDN using vm instances +  HTTPS LB, all right was set, im checking if works correclty,  when make some test to CDN Url's from browser or cURL appear content was cached, but when another user request same URL from different location but using same edge cache it doesnt found and create another new, someone having same problem ?:

sample:

URL: https://www.sample.com/url.htm

- User1/Location1(Dallas) ------------------------> DAL (not found first time and for second or third try,  generate CachedID DAL-XXXXXX1)

after that User1 create cache  another  user2 request same URL but from diferrent location but using same edge cache
URL: https://www.sample.com/url.htm

- User2/Location2(McAllen) ------------------------> DAL (not found generate Cached ID DAL-XXXXXX2)

Why if edge pop already have cached this URL is not serving and generate new cache fills for same URL?

Note:im not using query on any URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, DAL-XXXXXX1 and DAL-XXXXXX2 are separate caches. Google Cloud CDN operates multiple caches in many metropolitan areas, and content does not automatically replicate from one cache to another. You won't see cache hits from the DAL-XXXXXX2 cache on the first response served from DAL-XXXXXX2.

There's more information at [cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview#inserting-into-cache](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview#inserting-into-cache) and [cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/logging#what_is_logged](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/logging#what_is_logged).